# Paste formatted Excel range into Outlook task

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, task, paste

I've been trying to create a sub that would take some information from an Excel selection and create a new task on Outlook. The body of the task should feature the comment from the first cell (which it already does) but before all that I want to paste the range as it looks in Excel, then the comment, and then again, the range.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/WW77xgs.jpg]

Here's my code:

```
Sub CreateReminder()

Dim olApp As Object
Dim olRem As Object
Dim myRange As Range
Dim contact As String
Dim company As String
Dim city As String
Dim state As String
Dim cmt As comment
Dim comment As String
Dim strdate As Date
Dim remdate As Date

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olRem = olApp.CreateItem(3)

Set myRange = Selection


If ActiveCell.comment Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set cmt = ActiveCell.comment
End If
company = myRange.Columns(1).Text
contact = myRange.Columns(2).Text
If InStr(contact, "/") <> 0 Then
contact = Left(contact, InStr(contact, "/") - 1)
End If
city = myRange.Columns(7).Text
state = myRange.Columns(8).Text
myRange.Copy
comment = cmt.Text
strdate = Date
remdate = Format(Now)

rangeaddress = myRange.Address
wrksheetname = ActiveSheet.Name

With olRem

.Subject = "Call " & contact & " - " & company & " - " & city & ", " & state
.display
 SendKeys "{TAB 9}"
 SendKeys "^{v}"
 .body = Chr(10) & comment & Chr(10)
 '.startdate = strdate
 '.remindertime = remdate
 '.reminderset = True
 '.showcategoriesdialog
 End With

 Set olApp = Nothing
 Set olRem = Nothing

 End Sub
```

As you can see, I am able to paste using a SendKeys method, but it is sort of a hack, and not... sophisticated. I'm sure there's another way of doing it, any ideas?

I found code for pasting as HTML to an email, but as I understand, the Mail item allows for HTML, but not the Task item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook uses Word as an email editor. You can use the Word object model for making manipulatins on the message body. The WordEditor property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class (from the Word object model) which represents the body. You can read more about that way and all possible ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012.aspx).

That way you can use the [Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Range class to copy the range to the Clipboard. Then you can use the Paste method from the Word object model to paste data into the document which represents the message body.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, after reading and trying, I was unable to make it work. I guess I don't have enough knowledge. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Marking it as solved, because after trying for months, this was the solution. Thanks a lot.